# Display order status history in WooCommerce order detail page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

As a logistics provider, I want to show order status history in WooCommerce order detail page (like the screenshot below)

[image]

I tried this solution ([Keep and get order status history with their time stamps in Woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53105729/keep-and-get-order-status-history-with-their-time-stamps-in-woocommerce-3)) but no luck.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question lacks information to get any help from [so] users. Please take the [tour], and read through the [help], learn  [ask] a good question? to maximize your chance to get answer to your questions. If you run into a specific problem and if you're stuck, send a description of the problem, including a [mcve] and people will be very glad to help you.

Comment: It would be better if you put what type of result did you get